# AngularJS doesn't working with paypal

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, paypal, integration

I'm working in a project that I have to integrate angular with paypal plus. But when I put the script (paypal script) in a HTML the angular doesn't recognize the `PAYPAL.apps.PPP` script's variable I receives this error at console.

```
angular.js:13550 ReferenceError: PAYPAL is not defined
at eval (eval at globalEval (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js:343:5), <anonymous>:1:23)
at Function.globalEval (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js:343:5)
at domManip (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js:5291:15)
at jQuery.append (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js:5431:10)
at jQuery.<anonymous> (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js:5525:18)
at access (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js:3614:8)
at jQuery.html (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js:5492:10)
at link (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:25866:18)
at invokeLinkFn (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:9694:9)
at nodeLinkFn (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:9093:11) <div ng-include="'app/account/payment/panel/paypal.html'" class="ng-scope">"
```

HTML code:

```
<script src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/ppplus/ppplus.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="application/javascript">
var ppp = PAYPAL.apps.PPP({"approvalUrl": '.$approvalUrl.',"placeholder": "ppplus","mode": "sandbox"});
</script>
<div id="ppplus"> </div>
<button type="submit"
id="continueButton"
onclick="ppp.doContinue(); return false;">Continuar
</button>
```

Someone here know how to integrate paypal with angular or imports others scripts to be used in application.  o/

Comment: It seems like the paypal js is not getting loaded or the angular script is running before it is loaded.

Comment: The `PAYPAL` works with `jQuery`. Did you included `jQuery` script on header?

Comment: @plong0 I put the script in the index.html page and it works! Thanks man for the quickly answer! :P

Comment: @TeymurMardaliyerLennon jQuery already it's in the project. But thanks for helping! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the paypal js is not getting loaded or the angular script is running before it is loaded.

I put the script in the html index.html :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add jQuery library.You should include it before PAYPAL library.

Comment: Welcome to SO. I would consider expanding your answer a little bit.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working in a project with Angular 5 and I'd like to share my (almost) final solution to integrate Paypal Plus folowing the tipps from @Gleidson Ferreira.

On the head of the index.html:

```
<script src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/ppplus/ppplus.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

On the checkout.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
declare var PAYPAL: any;

@Component({
    selector: 'checkout',
    templateUrl: './checkout.component.html'
})
export class CheckoutComponent implements OnInit {
    paypalPlus: any;

    ngOnInit() {

    // TODO: add further customization to get your own proval URL dinamically
    this.paypalPlus = PAYPAL.apps.PPP(
    {
     'approvalUrl': 'https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=EC-31737613MN931841V',
      'placeholder': 'ppplus',
       'mode': 'sandbox'
    });
}

}
```

On checkout.component.html:

```
<div class="row" id="ppplus"> </div>
```